# How to rescale matplotlib figure to text?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to be able to autoscale a matplotlib figure to make arbitrarily placed text annotations visible. This is a challenge since artists other than Patches and Lines are not included in relim. For instance, the following text is out of the viewing area.

```
fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
t = matplotlib.text.Text(10,10, 'Hello')
ax.add_artist(t)
show()
```

The [docs cryptically mention](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.add_artist) using `update_datalim_numerix`, but how do I determine the correct bounding box in data units? Is there a method that will tell me the text bounding box size? How do I cope with an artist that has been subjected to multiple transformations?

Answer (score 0):

You can place your text relative to the axis, as explained [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.text as txt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
t = txt.Text(0.5,0.5, 'Hello',transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.add_artist(t)
plt.show()
```

This example will place your text always at the center of the plot, no matter how you change the axis.